# GDEBI Installer error

Tags: iso, gdebi

```
E: xipper: arch-independent-package-contains-binary-or-object usr/bin/extract-xiso
E: xipper: missing-dependency-on-libc needed by usr/bin/extract-xiso
E: xipper: debian-changelog-file-missing
E: xipper: no-copyright-file
W: xipper: description-synopsis-starts-with-article
E: xipper: extended-description-is-empty
W: xipper: unknown-section game
W: xipper: binary-without-manpage usr/bin/extract-xiso
W: xipper: binary-without-manpage usr/bin/xipper.gambas
E: xipper: md5sums-lists-nonexistent-file usr/bin/ripper.gambas
W: xipper: file-missing-in-md5sums usr/bin/xipper.gambas
W: xipper: postinst-has-useless-call-to-update-menus
W: xipper: postrm-has-useless-call-to-update-menus

Lintian finished with exit status 1
```

The above Lintian output from gdebi.
It says dependency is not satisfiable gambas2-gb-form.
i searched in synaptic manager and found gambas3-gb-form and installed.
I am trying to install xipper an iso extractor tool for xbox360 iso files but i get dependency error?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install it because there are missing dependencies.

As you can see, there is **gambas3-gb-form** into your repositories, **gambas2-gb-form is missing**...   :(

I think you try to install an old version of **xipper**.

If yes, try to install the latest version....    :)